# Do when loaded UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I want load request and when it loaded, I want get url. Can anyone tell what problem in my code?

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4876947&scope=audio&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.30&response_type=token")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL : url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    if let currURL: NSString = webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString! {
        getData(currURL)
    }
```

My error:

erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key web.'
*** First throw call stack

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by different things: (reported from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key))

- You've changed an `Outlet` property's name without updating the connection (can be solved via "Connections inspector)
- You did not set the right ViewController
- In general a wrong link between storyboard/xib and the code